# Can you access Vue component lifecycle hooks externally?

Tags: vue.js

I am using a component library within my web app and I'd like to attach functionality to one of the provided components.

So let's say I have a .vue file

```
<template>
   <div>
      ... some stuff
      <LibraryComponent />
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import LibraryComponent from 'library'

export default {
   components: {
      LibraryComponent
   }
}
</script>
```

I would love to be able to reach into the `LibraryComponent` and attach a method to the mounted hook from the parent. I figure I can update the code of the component itself in node_modules but that seems like a bad solution if the package gets updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue’s lifecycle hooks emit their own custom events.

Take a look at this article:
[Vue.js Component Hooks as Events](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-component-event-hooks)